# Воспроизведение потокового видео

Tags: java, видео

Доброго времени суток! Куда копать? может есть библиотеки? интересует функционал как в vlc - воспроизводить видео по url сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте библиотеку JavaCV.
Ну и что-то типа этого.

```
  FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(cameraUrl);
  Frame frame;
  grabber.start();
  FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(fileName, width, height, 1);
  recorder.setFormat("mp4");
  recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
  recorder.setSampleRate(grabber.getSampleRate());
  recorder.setFrameRate(grabber.getFrameRate());
  recorder.setVideoBitrate(grabber.getVideoBitrate());
  recorder.start();
  while (running && (frame = grabber.grabFrame()) != null) {                
    recorder.record(frame);
  }
  grabber.stop();
  recorder.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ один [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) - нативная либа , в кратце она умеет практически все. под ваше конкретное приложение вы подбираете какие кодеки какие форматы (и все остальное) будете использовать , билдите so - шки и добавляете в прилажение.

из минусов могу предсказать что билдить придется от суток до нескольких дней, если до этого вообще с нативными проектами дела не имели. сбилдить с помошью NDK на винде вообще теоритически невозможно. где то читал что подобных случаев не зафиксировано. но в остальнов очень даже все не плохно. разобравшись и собирая на линуксе быстро добьетесь необходимого результата. кстати иногда удается найти уже сбилженые so-шки и большая часть проблемм просто отпадает.

За помошью на irc каналы можно даже и не обращаться они там до денег жадные ))
главное что хочу заметить потоковое видео воспроизводится но mp4 работает быстрее все таки в нативном андроидовском плеере. тем более что в принцепе и там и там CV.